# Draggable image event in Kinect

Tags: javascript, dom-events, kineticjs

I'm creating a script where image is draggable and can change the image source when double clicked.

Moving the image works ok and when double clicking the image (event is dblclick) the image changes but same time appears as double where another identical image appears in the original position.

Code is:

```
var picture = new Image();
picture.onload = function() {
   var picture = new Kinetic.Image({
   x: 10,
   y: 10,
   image: picture,
   draggable: true,
   width: 100,
   height: 200
});

picture.on('dblclick', function() {
   picture.src = 'images/picture2.jpg';
});

layer.add(picture);
stage.add(layer);

}

picture.src = 'images/picture1.jpg';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because every time image.src is changed, image onload event is triggered.
and onload event creates a new Kinetic Image and add to the layer. 
Here is my version of your source code.

```
$( function() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 578,
      height: 200
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 140,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
      width: 106,
      height: 118,
      draggable:true
    });

    var images =[
        'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg',
        'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/wood-pattern.png'
    ];
    var imgIndex = 0;
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        yoda.setImage(imageObj);
        layer.draw();
    };

    yoda.on('dblclick',function() {
        imageObj.src = images[ imgIndex++ % 3 ];
    })

    layer.add(yoda);
    stage.add(layer);

});
```

I believe you follow the tutorial of the site, but it's not always correct. Also, please remember not to use the same variable picture on your source for image and kinetic object. it's very confusing

Comment: Ok I see. And Yes it works now thanks a lot! How about if I wanted to change the picture to next one by next double-click - e.g. 'Yoda' -> 'Darth-vader' -> '3rd picture'?

Comment: Edited the answer to change images around with double click. if helpful, could you mark this as accepted?

Comment: Hi, what if in a case I create 2 objects same time, Yoda1 and Yoda2 - how come the dblclick-event does not work anymore?